# Does the Skills & Endorsements section of LinkedIn matter for recruiters/employers?

Tags: linkedin

I found this as one of the more fun aspects of a profile in LinkedIn, however, I wonder if it even matters for employers and recruiters.

[image]

Do they see them as "bonus points" when making hiring decisions?

Comment: Skill-tags aren't very useful right now but there might some interesting developments in the future in this area for LinkedIn. They've just spend a ton of money to acquire the online learning site "lynda.com". The speculation is that there's going to be some way, using LinkedIn, to certify basic knowledge in particular skills/topics.

Comment: Linked-in poisoned their skills database when they started randomly soliciting endorsements forvskills we never claimed we had. At this point I won't touch Linked-in. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: It matters to the same extent as a "Skills" section on your CV matters. I've had recruiters and recruiting managers contact me directly because of the skills on my LinkedIn profile. However, the endorsements aren't necessarily worthwhile, as they prove nothing. They won't do any harm.

Answer (score 6):

> I wonder if it even matters for employers and recruiters. Do they see
>   them as "bonus points" when making hiring decisions?

**In my opinion as a hiring manager, they are completely worthless**. I have never - not even once - considered this section of an applicant's LinkedIn profile when considering the candidate. They are along the line of "Likes" - they take no thought or effort, and they can be applied anonymously - thus providing no value.

These skills and endorsements are made without any thought, without any proof, and without any degree of attainment.

I know some folks have endorsed my LinkedIn profile for skills which I don't have. I know that happens on a regular basis with me, and with others.

I wouldn't expect any value at all from these tags, and I certainly wouldn't waste any time trying to get them.

The "recommendations" are of a bit more value - they hold the potential for a real endorsement, particularly when written by someone know to the hiring manager.

Comment: Right there with you, Joe.  I have had colleagues from my early career endorse me for skills that I didn't develop until after we no longer worked together.  I could probably put "X-Wing Fighter Pilot" on my list of skills and get at least half a dozen endorsements on it.

Comment: Ooh, Star Wars fans!  Now you're talking! :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Mangle sentences I can.  A Jedi Master could I be! ;)

Comment: One might have said LinkedIn profiles were "completely worthless" a few years back. Even on their resume, job seekers will just write skills they have on their resume without thought or effort. You probably don't ask for proof of what's there unless you're inviting them for an interview. I agree the "Skills" section of LinkedIn is analogous to "likes" in Facebook or whatever, but this post seems to burn LinkedIn a little too badly.